# Keep a list of objects up to date over the network with C#

Tags: c#, list, object, networking, type-conversion

I'm an beginner programer who is trying to have a list of objects stored on a server and clients can connect and view/edit this list.

I will try to explain as best I can what my set up is.

Server:
This will hold a "Main List" that contains all the objects of that list type. When a Client wants an update this list needs to be passed to the client so they can read it.

Client:
The clients will read the updated list from the server and when they make a change to the list this change needs to be sent to the server.

Right now I'm thinking I make it to where only 1 client can edit the list at any time, and since things can be added/remove/changed/location in list changed I think it would be best to just have the client send their list to the server to replace the servers. This way since only 1 will be editing the list the list should stay updated.

My problem is that I can't find a somewhat simple way to send a list of objects through the network. Currently I might be able to pull it off by taking one object at a time converting it to XML then back, but since it's a list that requires much much code. I'm hoping someone knows of an easier way to move a list of objects through the network or converting a list of objects to a string/back again.

An easy example of what I'm doing is imagine pictures on a field that people can click and move, so I need to keep track of the order of images, the x/y and the image name. That is a rough example.

Please let me know what you think, any help would be appreciated. I'm a beginner so I apologize for any incorrect terminology.

Thank you.

Comment: You can serialize collections to XML/JSON.

Answer (score 1):

### Text Protocol

- XML
- JSON
- HTML/SOAP

XML works fine, especially if you're just learning. Its simple, and you've got enough to learn without worrying too much about efficiency at this point. Networking is a big subject!

JSON is a little less verbose than XML and equivalently as readable. I don't think C# has built in JSON serialization, so you'd need a third party library.

A web service would be easy.  The information exchanged would be greater, but this would be more scalable as web servers are pretty optimized. However, I do not suggest creating a simple web service as it will teach you less than working directly with sockets.

### Binary Protocol

- Built in serialization
- Third-party (Protobuf or Thrift)
- Serialize by hand

If the data needs to be sent/received fast, or you are wanting a server that's more scalable I suggest a binary protocol. Binary protocols are small, and are difficult to read.

If all clients and servers are C# based, just use the built in serialization C# offers. It is more verbose than other serialization solutions, but its the easiest solution. Again, as you are learning, I suggest using built in serialization if you need a binary protocol.

If not all the clients and servers are C# based, use a library like Google Protobufs or Apache Thrift which offers a way to serialize objects in a binary protocol in different languages pretty easily and very efficiently.

Last solution would be to serialize by hand. It will be the very fast, but inflexible, difficult, tedious, and hard to maintain. I do not suggest it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't send whole list back and forth.  Send only updates.

Server should hold compiled list, and should also hold a list of all changes from the time whole list is 'snapshot' last time.

Updates are:

- deletes
- edits
- additions

If you don't have much data, you can use simple xml for everything.

When received, every update should get serial number from the server.  That way each client knows last update number and can request new updates if available by polling.

Upon connect, client should:

- request snapshot from the server (receiving last ID snapshot-ed)

Later on, client should:

- poll regularly for new updates and store that updates in local list

Upon any change on the client, client should:

- pack the change and send it to the server

Implementing this will be both challenging and fun.  And will surely create some more questions here :)